# du -s /foldername gives totally different output with or without -h option

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-sierra, du

I just executed the following two commands in the terminal on my Mac (MacOS Sierra):

```
$ sudo du -s Documents/
11027432 Documents/

$ sudo du -hs Documents/
5.3G     Documents/
```

The info pane reports the following:

```
5.623.092.163 bytes (5,68 GB on disk) for 10.037 items
```

The first two options are totally off. How can this be explained?

Comment: I do not have OSX to check with, but on many a Unix like install du defaults to block size. 11027432 blocks of 512 bytes == 5.6GB == 5.3GiB

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/du.1.html), `du` "displays the file system block usage".  My guess is that you have 512-byte size blocks (so, half a KB).  Convert to GB (divide by 2 (to get KB), then by 1024 (to get MB) and then 1024 again), and it's roughly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Either you:

- did `-S` (uppercase) instead of `-s` (lowercase) on one of the two commands
- are  not in the same `pwd` and have two differents folder `Documents/`
- used `-b` on the first command

Try again, be sure using lower case `-s` and use absolute path.

Comment: I did copy paste the commands, so used lowercase s. Using an absolute path didn't help.